# Definition of a named route in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see plenty of examples of named routes all over the web, but I'm having trouble finding what exactly they are and why they are called named routes. Halp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named routes provide helper methods for generating the paths to get to a specific route. When you define a named route, you get two helper methods: `name_path` and `name_url`.

The difference between the two is that with `name_url` you get full url with protocol, domain name and port.

Example:

```
name_path -> /test
name_url -> http://localhost:3000:/test
```

So as you can see the benefit is that when you need to reference these paths you can use the names instead of spelling out the full route path.

In the following example which one would you rather type?

```
<%= link_to "Test", name_url %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to "Test", "http://localhost:3000/test" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Rails application named `Pharmacy` and you have created a controller for it named `patients`.

now automagically if you want to go to a url such as `"http://localhost:3000/pharmacy/patients"` the PATH that you can use inside your rails code will be `pharmacy_patients_path`

that word `_path` is a Rails thing.

I hope this helps you to understand the kind of pattern that is going on in Rails apps to created those routes.

Now to see them all you can run this command: `bundle exec rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers) are pretty good on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the docs tend to refer to named routes as if the reader already knows what they are... Which I don't.

Answer (score 0):

`named-route` simply means that

```
You can name the route so it can understandable to you  and others. 

It is same like naming your son. Obviously, you will give him some male-name like John 
Since *John* make  sense and give idea to another person that your son is male. 

We follow the same convention here on coding.
```

Not understood, re-read the answer and this [awesome guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).